# How do you add a button event to a button via script with parameters included Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button

I am trying to add an onClick event to a bunch of buttons on screen that I have Instantiated. But the function I am calling needs parameters. When I put the parameters the code doesn’t run but when I don’t it runs but the function doesn’t do what it is supposed to because it doesn’t have the right parameters. Any ideas?

```
public void PreviewButtonLook(Image previewPart, Sprite previewSprite) 
{
   previewPart.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = previewSprite; 
}

button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(PreviewButtonLook(previewPart, options[i]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick.AddListener()` accepts a delegate of zero parameters.

You can create a zero-parameter anonymous function and pass it as a delegate.

This zero parameter anonymous function can call another function and pass it as many parameters as you want.

```
button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate {
    PreviewButtonLook(previewPart, options[i]);
});
```

But be aware of [function closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/1663383).

Comment: Thank you, so much!

Comment: simply as lambda expression: `button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => PreviewButtonLook(previewPart, options[I]));` Very careful, though with that `i`! be aware of [variable capturing](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions) You will have to store it in a local variable like `var index = i;` and rather pass in `options[index]` ;)

Comment: (Lambdas implicitly cast to delegates when the type is known, like it is here).

Comment: Thank you! I have heard a lot about lambda, here and from other people. Is it something that I should learn extensively? If so, any recommendations on how?

Comment: @Hankery Lambdas are very powerful expressions that allow you to simplify your code and make it more readable. Here's a primer: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-lambda-expression

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that out.